# ZF and weakly inaccessible cardinals

Tags: logic, set-theory

This question should probably have been asked 3 years ago (perhaps it has and was removed for some reason?)

In 2011, Alexander Kiselev claimed to have proved in ZF that there are no weakly inaccessible cardinals. He posted two long papers on the arXiv (see here : http://logiciansdoitwithmodels.com/2011/08/17/fom-posting-on-a-kiselevs-claim-that-there-are-no-weakly-inaccessible-cardinals-in-zf/. There were a few reactions in 2011, e.g. this one : http://www.cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2011-August/015698.html

However, I could google absolutely nothing talking about that after 2011.

So, I was wondering if anybody knows what is going on here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From [this blog post](http://proofannaalexander.blogspot.co.at/2013/03/an-open-letter-to-mr-howard-becker.html) it appears that the papers were submitted to the JSL, and were rejected; this happened in August 2000. Alexander Kiselev died in 2012.

Comment: @ArthurFischer Thanks for the link. How did you find it (that is, using which "key words")?

Comment: My exact Google search was `Kiselev inaccessible`, and that post was the 9th item on the list.

Comment: OK; thanks again.

Comment: @arjafi: Um so do you know of any refutation of the paper endorsed by an expert? It's been so 17 years since then and yet Google doesn't turn up anything more than some ['it-seems-to-me' comment from some FOM participant](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2011-August/015697.html).

Comment: @user21820 No, I am not aware of an specific refutations of the paper by experts.